# Changing Tkinter label while app is still running

Tags: python, tkinter

Could not find exact answer to my question in other posts. What I am looking for is the way to update my label while my other function is running. I tried to first change the label and then call the my_function(), but still label is not updating however my_function() is running and printing results in terminal. I am totally new to Tkinter and as far as I understood, while we do not hit window.mainloop() my label would not update. Is there any methods to update the label while other function is running?

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, Label, Scrollbar, Text, filedialog

def my_function(directory: str) -> None:
    for item in os.scandir(directory):
        if item.is_file:
            # print(f'File name: {item.name}')
            text_area.insert(END, f'File name: {item.name}\n')


def select_folder() -> None:
    '''
    Tkinter function for button,
    user can select folder.
    '''

    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    status.config(text='Status: Work in progress, please wait!')
    text_area.insert(END, 'Visited folders:\n')
    my_function(path)
    status.config(text='Status: Done!')


# Start the app window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('PDF maker')
window.geometry('400x400')

# Status Label
status = Label(window, text='Status: Select the folder')
status.pack()

# Button for selecting folder
button = tk.Button(window, text='Select Folder', command=select_folder)
button.pack(side='bottom', pady=30)

# Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbars
v_s = Scrollbar(window)
v_s.pack(side='right', fill='y')

h_s = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
h_s.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

# Text area for result output
text_area = Text(
    window,
    wrap='none',
    font=('Times New Roman', 13),
    yscrollcommand=v_s.set,
    xscrollcommand=h_s.set
)
text_area.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=True, fill='both')

# Adding scrollability to text
v_s.config(command=text_area.yview)
h_s.config(command=text_area.xview)

window.mainloop()
```

---

**Update**

Or should I create 2 functions for one button? First function will change the label and text, and second function will run my_func().

Comment: Please provide your full code, *filedialog* for instance is not defined and tkinter not imported accordingly.

Comment: @Bialomazur just updated it) Sorry forgot about imports

Comment: my_function is not defined...

Comment: not sure why you need it, but I added similar my_function()

Comment: well the name 'my_function' is generic as can be and thus it's quite hard to judge which role it plays in this case. I'll write my answer now, thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, the answer is very simple.

Try this:

```
#...
def select_folder() -> None:
    """
    Tkinter function for button,
    user can select folder.
    """
    status.config(text="Status: Work in progress, please wait!") # switched lines here
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    text_area.insert(END, "Visited folders:\n")
    my_function(path)
    status.config(text="Status: Done!")

#...
```

Previously it did not work as intended, because `filedialog.askdirectory()` blocks the **program-flow** ( similarly to `input()` ).

Comment: thanks it was pretty simple solution) What about text_area.insert() inside of my_function()? Is it possible to update label so the text_area will output results one by one, instead of putting everything at once

Comment: Sure, I have a solution in mind by using an artificial delay for each insertion, but I think this should be put in a new question. You can mention me in a comment so that I get notified as soon as you've posted it.